# Drop down list renders over modal page

Tags: javascript, html, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm making an HTML application in Apex 5

I have a drop down list, which is not intended to be directly selected by the user. When the user clicks on it (actually when the item gets focused) it opens a modal page to display the list of items to be selected.

(I do this because the drop down list is not capable of showing arbitrary HTML elements).

At focus event, a javascript triggers and

- Blurs the select list (to make it lose focus)
- Opens a modal page, displaying the items to be selected. The modal page automatically selects the item.

The problem is that at  user click on the list, his drop down list is displayed, and rendered over the modal page.

I show the problem and the expected result on this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnTP4.png

To avoid the drop down list to be rendered over the modal page, I tried

- To disable the drop down list, but it also disables his focusability and clickability.
- To set his "Size" property to 1 and to 0. It does not impedes the drop down list to be rendered.

Comment: you need to show use some code so we can help

Comment: @hjm I added the code. Not sure id it helps, because is APEX

Answer (score 0):

try giving the modal a greater z-index than the dropdown.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I disable the select list, then open the modal page, then wait 500 miliseconds, and enable the select list

```
var p1_SelectList=document.getElementById("P1_My_Select_List");

p1_SelectList.disabled = "disabled";

//Open modal page

setTimeout(function(){
    p1_SelectList.disabled = "";
}, 500);
```